# docusign signhere tab with other tab- not work

Tags: docusignapi

Here is my envelope.

I can get the sign here tab not working fine with all other tabs. Why sign here tab and all other tab not working together. There does not seem to be any good help on the on this. So I tried it all together but response return me as bad request(400).

So how can pass this all tab. Any suggestion?

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="/restapi">
   <emailSubject>Document of Signing</emailSubject>
   <emailBlurb>Initiated by xxxxx</emailBlurb>
   <emailBlurb>fgfdg'gfgdsg</emailBlurb>
   <brandId>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</brandId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <documents>
      <document>
         <documentId>1</documentId>
         <name>Test-New-docu-sign_S.docx</name>
         <transformPdfFields>true</transformPdfFields>
      </document>
   </documents>
   <recipients>
      <signers>
         <signer>
            <recipientId>2</recipientId>
            <email>xxxx@xxxxx.com</email>
            <name>Test New docu sign</name>
            <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
            <tabs>
               <signHereTabs>
                  <signHere>
                     <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                     <anchorString>sign1</anchorString>
                     <documentId>1</documentId>
                     <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                     <xPosition>10</xPosition>
                     <yPosition>10</yPosition>
                     <name>Sign Here</name>
                  </signHere>
               </signHereTabs>
               <fullNameTabs>
                  <fullName>
                     <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                     <anchorMatchWholeWord>true</anchorMatchWholeWord>
                     <anchorString>Test Usil name</anchorString>
                     <documentId>1</documentId>
                     <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                  </fullName>
               </fullNameTabs>
               <dateSignedTabs>
                  <dateSigned>
                     <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                     <anchorMatchWholeWord>true</anchorMatchWholeWord>
                     <anchorString>Signeddate</anchorString>
                     <tabLabel>Signeddate</tabLabel>
                     <documentId>1</documentId>
                     <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                     <xPosition>10</xPosition>
                     <yPosition>10</yPosition>
                  </dateSigned>
               </dateSignedTabs>
               <radioGroupTabs>
                  <radioGroup>
                     <documentId>1</documentId>
                     <groupName>Select</groupName>
                     <radios>
                        <radio>
                           <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                           <anchorMatchWholeWord>true</anchorMatchWholeWord>
                           <anchorString>Yes</anchorString>
                           <required>true</required>
                           <value>Choice1</value>
                           <xPosition>10</xPosition>
                           <yPosition>10</yPosition>
                        </radio>
                        <radio>
                           <anchorCaseSensitive>true</anchorCaseSensitive>
                           <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                           <anchorMatchWholeWord>true</anchorMatchWholeWord>
                           <anchorString>No</anchorString>
                           <required>true</required>
                           <value>Choice2</value>
                           <xPosition>15</xPosition>
                           <yPosition>10</yPosition>
                        </radio>
                     </radios>
                     <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                  </radioGroup>
               </radioGroupTabs>
            </tabs>
         </signer>
      </signers>
   </recipients>
```

Comment: perhaps `<signHere>` also wants the `<tabLabel></tabLabel>` label?

Answer (score 1):

There few issues in your XML:

1. Two `<emailBlurb>` are present
2. `<transformPdfFields>` is not valid for docx, you need to set  only for PDF that too when you have pdf field property names in the DocuSign field property styles
3. `<recipientId>2</recipientId>` is set as 2 inside signer node, whereas `<recipientId>1</recipientId>` is set in each tab node. So both should be same, if signer is declared with recipientId 2 then eachtab should also have recipientId 2.
4. In `Sign Here` tab, you are mixing two strategies, anchorString and X/Y position, which in my understanding is not correct. Either you should have anchorString or X/Y position.
5. Same issue with `DateSigned` as mentioned for SignHere.
6. If you are going with X/Y position then X/Y position should be different for each tab, I am seeing you have same X/Y position for `SignHere`, `DateSigned` and `radio-Yes`. Putting same X/Y position will overlap one tab over other.